# WPF Multiple Converter calls after sorting DataGrid on Cell Click

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

https://github.com/milanmilas/WPFDataGridSortingColorConverter

I have a BackgroundColor Converter on my DataGrid, that is called once per cell:

```
Converter Called: Ana , 25
Converter Called: Ana , 25
Converter Called: Dan , 5
Converter Called: Dan , 5
Converter Called: Mike , 65
Converter Called: Mike , 65
```

DataGrid has Click Event on each cell that updates one of the cells values ("just for testing"). Converter will fire 3 times per cell click, but as soon as I order Grid Rows by clicking on the Name header, it will fire multiple times, Its like duplicated cells are created after sorting:

```
 Age Incremented
Converter Called: Dan , 10
Converter Called: Dan , 10
Converter Called: Dan , 10
Converter Called: Dan , 10
Converter Called: Dan , 10
Converter Called: Dan , 10
Converter Called: Dan , 10


<Window.Resources>
    <local:SimpleBrushColorConverter x:Key="SimpleColorConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding People}" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" SortMemberPath="Age">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Name="Name" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Age" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Name="Age" Text="{Binding Path=Age, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="{Binding Path=Age, Converter={ StaticResource SimpleColorConverter}}" MouseLeftButtonDown="OnCellMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    PeopleViewModel vm = new PeopleViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = vm;
    }

    private void OnCellMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("");
        Debug.WriteLine("Age Incremented");
        vm.People.First().Age++;
    }
}

public class SimpleBrushColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Simple Converter Called: " + values + " , " + values);
        if ((int)values < 18) return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(250, 0, 0));
        if (60 > (int)values && (int)values > 18) return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 250, 0));
        return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 250));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class PeopleViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People2 { get; set; }

    public PeopleViewModel()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>(
            new List<Person>
                {
                    new Person() {Age = 5, Name = "Dan"},
                    new Person() {Age = 25, Name = "Ana"},
                    new Person() {Age = 65, Name = "Mike"}
                }
            );

    }
}

public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class Person : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private int _age;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set { _age = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use MultiValueConverter and bind to TextBlock as well, in the converter after sorting and clicking on the cell I can see that first Converter call is for the TextBlock with old value that has "IsVisible =False". The second call is for the real visible cell. Sorting again will add additional TextBlock with "IsVisible=False" for one of the old values. This continues up to 10 TextBlock's. At some point some of the TextBlock's get recycled so they don't appear in the converter call anymore.

Will use "IsVisible" in the converter to distinguish between valid TextBlocks but still not sure why this is happening?

```
public class MultiBrushColorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Simple Converter Called: " + values[0] + " , " + values[0]);
        var textBlock = values[1];
        if ((int)values[0] < 18) return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(250, 0, 0));
        if (60 > (int)values[0] && (int)values[0] > 18) return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 250, 0));
        return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 250));
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Age" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Name="Age" Text="{Binding Path=Age}" MouseLeftButtonDown="OnCellMouseLeftButtonDown">
                <TextBlock.Background>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiColorConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Age" />
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Background>
             </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```